# How to set an alias of a command and it's argument in Windows Powershell?

Tags: powershell, config, alias

I am on a Windows 11 machine (Powershell v5.1) and I am trying to alias the rust rewrite of [coreutils](https://github.com/uutils/coreutils) to appropriate commands in powershell. For example, I need to call `coreutils echo` to access the `echo` command and similarly for `mv`, `cat`, `cp` etc. So I wrote a function to output the command string, and I am passing it to the `Set-Alias` cmdlet.

However I am getting the following error.

```
echo : The term 'coreutils echo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ echo
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (coreutils echo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Here is my powershell config.

```
# neovim config alias
function Open-NeovimConfig {
  $CurrPath = pwd
  cd C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\nvim\lua\user\
  nvim .\init.lua
  cd $CurrPath
  }

# coreutils command specifier
function Coreutils-Cmd($Cmd) {
    return "coreutils $Cmd"
}

Set-Alias nvimc Open-NeovimConfig
Set-Alias ls lsd -Option AllScope
Set-Alias echo (Coreutils-Cmd "echo") -Option AllScope
Set-Alias cat (Coreutils-Cmd "cat") -Option AllScope
Set-Alias cp (Coreutils-Cmd "cp") -Option AllScope
```

EDIT: Based on Santiago's comment, I did the following. However, there is a lot of repeated logic. Any suggestions to improve?

```
function echo {coreutils echo $args}
function cat {coreutils cat $args}
function rm {coreutils rm $args}
function cp {coreutils cp $args}
function mv {coreutils mv $args}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work but I needed to write a lot of functions. Any suggestions to improve this? Added more info in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could automate the process using a loop and `Set-Item` to dynamically define those functions:

```
foreach($cmd in 'echo', 'cat', 'rm', 'cp', 'mv') {
    Remove-Alias $cmd -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Set-Item function:$cmd -Value { coreutils $cmd $args }.GetNewClosure()
}
```

This only works because the name of the function happens to also be the same as the argument passed to `coreutils`. Also, the use of `.GetNewClosure()` is needed here, otherwise the scriptblocks would use the last value of `$cmd`.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. How should I modify this if I want this to happen for every command in `coreutils`?

Comment: @AdityaWagh I don't know the commands in `coreutils` but if you have a full list of them then you can change the collection in the loop and it would work

Comment: @AdityaWagh If you put all 119 command names into the loop header it won't be very readable. ;-) You could put them into a here-string and use `-split` to create an array: https://gist.github.com/zett42/72fe42c418d53ad03d5e17ffd7fd8104

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon: Cool. Reminds me of how all the drive-letter-named functions have the identical defintion: `{ Set-Location $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name }`.